# Android BLE onCharacteristicChanged() using notify not triggered

Tags: java, android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I made an app that communicates with an device via BLE. I wrote everything that was required for it's communication. The device receives the sent value via `characteristic.setValue()` , but doesn't return feedback in the method `onCharacteristicChanged` as is supposed to, in despite that has the descriptor set for notification. For instance i send `"GTN"` and should get `"GTN deviceId"` (like on iOS), but it calls just `onCharacteristicWrite()`. Checked also what properties the characteristic does support. It supports `PROPERTY_NOTIFY` & `PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE`. I ran out of ideas why it doesn't want to get that callback message. Can someone check and try to tell me if I made some big mistakes while sending/subscribing ??

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_LOCATION = 3;
    private static final int BLUETOOTH_ENABLED = -1;
    private static final int LOCATION_ENABLED = -1;
    private static final int MANUFACTURER_ID = xxxxx;
    private static final UUID SERVICE =xxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    private static final UUID CHARACTERISTIC =xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    private static final UUID DESCRIPTOR = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    private final static String TAG = "BLE";
    private byte[] mfrData;
    private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt;
    private BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner;
    private BluetoothGattService customService;
    private BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                gatt.discoverServices();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(SERVICE);
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC);
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            enableDataNotifications(gatt, characteristic);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite: ");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicChanged: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            super.onDescriptorRead(gatt, descriptor, status);
            Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorRead: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(final BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
            Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite: ");
            checkCharacteristicProperties(gatt.getService(SERVICE).getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC));
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    writeDataToCharCommand("GTN", gatt);
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReliableWriteCompleted(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onReliableWriteCompleted(gatt, status);
            Log.d(TAG, "onReliableWriteCompleted: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
            super.onReadRemoteRssi(gatt, rssi, status);
            Log.d(TAG, "onReadRemoteRssi: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status) {
            super.onMtuChanged(gatt, mtu, status);
            Log.d(TAG, "onMtuChanged: ");
        }

    };
    private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            if (result.getScanRecord() != null && result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData(MANUFACTURER_ID) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onScanResult: found device");
                bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
                boolean isBonded = result.getDevice().createBond();
                if (isBonded) {
                    bluetoothGatt = result.getDevice().connectGatt(MainActivity.this, false, bluetoothGattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results);
            Log.d(TAG, "onBatchScanResults: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            Log.d(TAG, "onScanFailed: ");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupBluetoothData();
        checkIfSupportedBluetooth();
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    private void checkCharacteristicProperties(BluetoothGattCharacteristic pChar) {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCharacteristicProperties: PROPERTY_READ " + ((pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) != 0));
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCharacteristicProperties: PROPERTY_NOTIFY " + ((pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0));
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCharacteristicProperties: PROPERTY_BROADCAST " + ((pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_BROADCAST) != 0));
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCharacteristicProperties: PROPERTY_EXTENDED_PROPS " + ((pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_EXTENDED_PROPS) != 0));
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCharacteristicProperties: PROPERTY_INDICATE " + ((pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) != 0));
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCharacteristicProperties: PROPERTY_SIGNED_WRITE " + ((pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_SIGNED_WRITE) != 0));
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCharacteristicProperties: PROPERTY_WRITE " + ((pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) != 0));
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCharacteristicProperties: PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE " + ((pChar.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) != 0));
    }

    private void setupBluetoothData() {
        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    }

    private void checkIfSupportedBluetooth() {
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (!hasGrantedLocationPermission()) {
            requestLocationPermission();
        } else {
            checkIfBluetoothEnabled();
        }
    }

    private boolean hasGrantedLocationPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestLocationPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
    }

    private void checkIfBluetoothEnabled() {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
        } else {
            displayLocationSettingsRequest();
        }
    }

    private void displayLocationSettingsRequest() {
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {

                final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS: {
                        scanForDevices();
                        break;
                    }
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED: {
                        try {
                            status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_ENABLE_LOCATION);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE: {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH: {
                if (resultCode == BLUETOOTH_ENABLED) {
                    displayLocationSettingsRequest();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Restart app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_LOCATION: {
                if (resultCode == LOCATION_ENABLED) {
                    scanForDevices();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Restart app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void scanForDevices() {
        Log.d(TAG, "scanForDevices: ");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .build();

        ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                .setManufacturerData(0x0361, mfrData)
                .build();

        bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(Collections.singletonList(scanFilter),
                scanSettings, scanCallback);

    }

    private String translate(byte[] value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new String(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    checkIfBluetoothEnabled();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Restart app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void writeDataToCharCommand(String data, BluetoothGatt gatt) {
        Log.d(TAG, "writeDataToCharCommand: ");
        gatt.getService(SERVICE).getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC).setValue(data);
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(gatt.getService(SERVICE).getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC));
    }

    private void enableDataNotifications(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic) {
        Log.d(TAG, "enableDataNotifications: ");
        boolean enabled = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
        if (enabled) {
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you are calling setCharacteristicNotification twice in the service discovery and also in enableDataNotifications. Is this really required. Add a queuing method for the bluetooth le calls. Also try adding a delay of 600 ms before discovering the services.

Answer (score 0):

i have notification work flawlessly with BLE.

i created this method to mark a characteristics notification enabled.

```
public void markCharForNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic readableChar) {

        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(readableChar, true);

        List<BluetoothGattDescriptor> listDescr = readableChar.getDescriptors();

        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = listDescr.get(0);
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

    }
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run the checkCharacteristicProperties on the notify characteristic also.

Anyway, the correct way to enable notifications is to check the properties first and enable notify or indicate, based on those properties:

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR_UUID);
    int properties = characteristic.getProperties();
    if (descriptor != null) {
        if ((properties & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        } else if ((properties & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) > 0) {
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
        }
        gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Hope this helps.