# calling connectGatt() and createBond() together

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf51

I'm trying to create a bond between my Android phone and my device. Before they were connected well by calling `device.connectGatt()` with my `gattCallback`. But now as I want to also want to add bonding by calling `device.createBond()`, my `onConnectionStateChange` shows an alternate pattern of connected and disconnected with the status code 0 when connected and 8 when disconnected. Here is my snippet of code of how I'm trying to use `connectGatt` and `createBond` together.

```
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        System.out.println("on scan result");
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
                if (device.createBond()) {
                    System.out.println("create bond success");
                    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mListener.retrieveApplicationContext(), true, mGattCallback);
                }
                else System.out.println("create bond sb");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there anything wrong by calling these two methods in this way? I searched the internet for creating bonds but none of the pages uses createBond and connectGatt together. I only got a hint from this post about how to call these two methods this way: [Android BLE onCharacteristicChanged() using notify not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409638/android-ble-oncharacteristicchanged-using-notify-not-triggered)

Also, my `BroadCastReceiver` always shows device bonding as well but never shows device bonded.

Answer (score 1):

The `createBond` method will internally first connect to the device if not connected using `autoConnect` set to false. That means the bonding attempt will be aborted after 30 seconds if the device never connects successfully during that time. But you connect using `autoConnect` set to true, which means no timeout. So if it for some reason takes 31 seconds to connect, the bonding will not happen.

If I were you, I'd first connect the device myself, and when the device has successfully connected and services discovered (and checked that it has the desired services), call `createBond`, to make sure everything seems right before bonding.

Status code 8 means "Connection Timeout". This means the connection was up and running but dropped unexpectedly on the radio level, which is not a software error, but something that happens naturally as you go out of range but also due to bad hw such as buggy firmware or bad crystal clock frequency.

Comment: So you're saying status code 8 can be the issue of the firmware side? Could you give more specific firmware issues? I have been trying to figure out whether it was the fault of the android side or the firmware side.

Comment: For example if the firmware code crashes and the device reboots.

Comment: I actually did try calling createBond() after the services are found, but the same thing happens as well: status code 0 connected and status code 8 disconnected back and forth. I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be because the firmware code crashes or the device reboots, because after I removed createBond() method everything works just as fine. Are there any other possible reasons from the firmware side that causes this status code 0 and 8 back and forth pattern?

Comment: This is like asking why a web server stops responding after a particular request has been sent to it. Use a BLE air sniffer or use a debugger to maybe find out what's going on.